# ElasticSearch - Aggregation + Range + Term query

Tags: elasticsearch

With ElasticSearch, I would like to get the sum of a field for a period with filtering on a value of an other field.

I defined this mapping:

```
PUT match-orders
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "mappings": {
        "order": {
            "_all": {"enabled": false},
            "properties": {
                "matchTime": {"type": "date", "index": "true"},
                "product_id": {"type": "keyword", "index": "true"},
                "size": {"type": "float", "index": "true"},
                "price": {"type": "float", "index": "true"},
                "side": {"type": "keyword", "index": "true"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the sum for a range:

```
POST /match-orders/_search?pretty
{
    "aggs" : {
    "price_ranges" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "matchTime",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "from" : "2017-09-10T18:00:00Z", "to" : "2017-09-10T18:15:00Z" }
                ]
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "result" : { "sum" : { "field" : "size" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the documents which contain a specific term:

```
POST /match-orders/_search?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "term" : { "side" : "sell" } 
    }
}
```

But how can I combine these two queries?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to merge your query with your aggregation like this:

```
POST /match-orders/_search?pretty
{
    "query": {
        "term" : { "side" : "sell" } 
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "price_ranges" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "matchTime",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "from" : "2017-09-10T18:00:00Z", "to" : "2017-09-10T18:15:00Z" }
                ]
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "result" : { "sum" : { "field" : "size" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "all_xxx" : {
      "terms" : { "field" : "xxx", "size" : 1000 }
    },
    "custom_range" : {
      "range" : { "field" : "datetime", "ranges" : [{ "from" : "2020-09-11 12:06:27" }, { "to" : "now" }] }
    }
  },
  size: 0
}
```

Comment: This query returns both the aggregation for documents matching "terms" and the aggregation for documents matching "range", but do not combine the two conditions (documents matching "terms" AND "range")

Answer (score -1):

Following interpolation of the terms query should do -

```
POST /match-orders/_search?pretty
{
    "aggs" : {
        "price_ranges" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "matchTime",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "from" : "2017-09-10T18:00:00Z", "to" : "2017-09-10T18:15:00Z" }
                ]
            },
            "terms" : {
                 "field" : "side",
                 "include" : ["sell"]
             },
            "aggs" : {
                "result" : { "sum" : { "field" : "size" } }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values

Comment: This query returns an error: "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Found two aggregation type definitions in [price_ranges]: [range] and [terms]",
        "line": 10,
        "col": 23
      }
    ]

Comment: This query is invalid, range and term can not be added like this